# Create a default folder structure & insert current Date in Terminal by single command?

Tags: macos, terminal

I often find myself creating the same structure by hand in finder for new projects, how can I quicken this process with a single Terminal Command?

Example of structure & command:

Terminal
$ cf Project_Name      //cf for CreateFolder

Creates a folder in the current Path with current Date -> YYMMDD Project_Name

In that folder a custom structure:

_CI

_layout

_layout/_screens

_material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
mkdir -p "`date "+%Y%m%d"` Project_Name"/_layout/_screens
```

should do the trick.  It is plain vanilla unix.

Comment: Great thanks, I added this now to my .functions
cf () {
 mkdir -p "`date "+%y%m%d"` $1"/_layout/_screens
 mkdir -p "`date "+%y%m%d"` $1"/_material/
 cd "`date "+%y%m%d"` $1"
 open .
}